# Aggregation by nested objects with filter in ElasticSearch 6

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have set of documents that represent property units in ElasticSearsh 6. Every property has nested array of weekly rates:

```
{
   "name" : "Completely Awesome Cabin"
   "rates" : [
      {
         "start": "2018-06-09T00:00:00",
         "end": "2018-06-16T00:00:00",
         "weeklyRate": 100.0,
      },
      {
         "start": "2018-06-16T00:00:00",
         "end": "2018-06-23T00:00:00",
         "weeklyRate": 200.0,
      }
      ...
   ]    
   ...
}
```

I am performing some filtering by several options including dates. I need to add aggregations that would give me minimum and maximum weeklyRate between all units that passed the filters. It should be some kind of nested aggregation with filter, I suppose. How can I do this?

Comment: Do `start` and `end` across _rate_ objects ever overlap with other _rate_ objects, or do they always start on the same day and have the same duration (7 days)? I'm trying to understand if an aggregation on `start` only would be sufficient to infer a week duration

Comment: Yes, each rate object represents the rent cost for one particular week. They don't overlap with each other. Rent cost changes from one week to another, So when I am searching available properties for instance from 06/01 to 07/01(i do it by other filters), I need to know the maximum and minimum weekly rate between all available properties for these dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in addition to very usefull and helpfull answer from Russ Cam I want to post the final implementation, that does exactly what I needed. This is NEST aggregation:

```
.Aggregations(a => a
    .Nested("budget_bound", n => n
        .Path(p => p.Rates)
        .Aggregations(aa => aa
            .Filter("by_start_date", fl => fl
                .Filter(fld => fld 
                    .DateRange(dr => dr
                        .Field(f => f.Rates.First().Start)
                        .GreaterThanOrEquals(checkIn)
                        .LessThanOrEquals(checkOut)))
                     .Aggregations(md => md
                         .Min("min_budget", m => m
                             .Field(f => f.Rates.First().WeeklyRate))
                         .Max("max_budget", m => m
                             .Field(f => f.Rates.First().WeeklyRate))
                      )
                 )
            )
       )
```

Here is the corresponding ES query:

```
"aggs": {
"budget_bound": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "rates"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_start_date": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "rates.start": {
            "gte": "2018-06-29T00:00:00+07:00", // parameter values
            "lte": "2018-07-06T00:00:00+07:00"  // parameter values
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_budget": {
          "min": {
            "field": "rates.weeklyRate"
          }
        },
        "max_budget": {
          "max": {
            "field": "rates.weeklyRate"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

The thing for me was to figure out how to nest aggregations to add filtering of nested collection before getting minimum and maximum aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete example running with NEST 6.1.0

```
private static void Main()
{
    var index = "default";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(index);

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    if (client.IndexExists(index).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(index);

    client.CreateIndex(index, c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<MyDocument>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Nested<Rate>(n => n
                        .AutoMap()
                        .Name(nn => nn.Rates)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    client.Bulk(b => b
        .IndexMany(new[] {
            new MyDocument
            {
                Name = "doc 1",
                Rates = new []
                {
                    new Rate
                    {
                        Start = new DateTime(2018, 6, 9),
                        End = new DateTime(2018, 6, 16),
                        WeeklyRate = 100
                    },
                    new Rate
                    {
                        Start = new DateTime(2018, 6, 16),
                        End = new DateTime(2018, 6, 23),
                        WeeklyRate = 200
                    }
                }
            },
            new MyDocument
            {
                Name = "doc 2",
                Rates = new []
                {
                    new Rate
                    {
                        Start = new DateTime(2018, 6, 9),
                        End = new DateTime(2018, 6, 16),
                        WeeklyRate = 120
                    },
                    new Rate
                    {
                        Start = new DateTime(2018, 6, 16),
                        End = new DateTime(2018, 6, 23),
                        WeeklyRate = 250
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
    );

    var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
        // apply your filtering in .Query(...) e.g. applicable date range
        .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
        // don't return documents, just calculate aggregations
        .Size(0)
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Nested("nested_start_dates", n => n
                .Path(f => f.Rates)
                .Aggregations(aa => aa
                    .DateHistogram("start_dates", dh => dh
                        .Field(f => f.Rates.First().Start)
                        .Interval(DateInterval.Day)
                        .MinimumDocumentCount(1)
                        .Aggregations(aaa => aaa
                            .Min("min_rate", m => m
                                .Field(f => f.Rates.First().WeeklyRate)
                            )
                            .Max("max_rate", m => m
                                .Field(f => f.Rates.First().WeeklyRate)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    var nested = searchResponse.Aggregations.Nested("nested_start_dates");

    var startBuckets = nested.DateHistogram("start_dates").Buckets;

    foreach(var start in startBuckets)
    {
        var min = start.Min("min_rate").Value;
        var max = start.Max("max_rate").Value;

        Console.WriteLine($"{start.KeyAsString} - min: {min}, max: {max}");
    }
}

public class MyDocument
{
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<Rate> Rates {get;set;}
}

public class Rate
{
    public DateTime Start {get;set;}

    public DateTime End {get;set;}

    public double WeeklyRate {get;set;}
}
```

which prints the following to the console

```
2018-06-09T00:00:00.000Z - min: 100, max: 120
2018-06-16T00:00:00.000Z - min: 200, max: 250
```

You may also be interested in other metrics aggregations like [Stats Agggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-stats-aggregation.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer! The only problem with this implementation is that rates in aggregation are not filtered by some date range. There must be two paramaters `from` and `to`. I don't understand how to apply them to filter buckets.

Comment: Apply a range query in a bool filter clause to match only documents with rates in the given date range. This will return all the rates of matching documents. Then may need to make the DateHistogram a sub-aggregation of a Filter aggregation to filter out rates that in matching documents that do not fall in the given range.

Comment: You were right! Making DateHistogram subaggregation under filter helps. Could you please add filter aggreation over DateHistogram so I can mark your answer as a completely correct?